# Local Login using passport.js is giving preflight error and access-conrol-all-origin error

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

so I am using passport.js in an Express app. It is giving me the below error. when I hit the "/local/login" route with username and password.

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/loginsuccess' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/auth/local/login') from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Code to initialize cookie session and passport session. The server is running on localhost:8000

#index.js

```
var corsOptions = {
  origin: ["http://localhost:8080"],
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
  // some legacy browsers (IE11, various SmartTVs) choke on 204
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(
  cookieSession({
    keys: ["hellofromotherside"],
    maxAge: 24 * 60 * 60 * 100,
  })
);

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

#user.js

```
router.post(
  "/local/login",
  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:8080/loginsuccess",
  })
);
router.get(
  "/google/login",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:8080/loginsuccess",
  })
);
```

The only problem is that it is not redirecting. I am using the same thing with google strategy and it's redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Above error is because of Option request type. It is a preflight request which fires with any other request(POST,DEL,etc.). Here is Docs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#preflighted_requests

So I have solved the preflight request with appropriate headers. But I am not redirecting, instead I am sending back JSON response with login success.

```
router.options("*", (req, res) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", LOCAL_ORIGIN);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  res.end();
});
router.post("/local/login", passport.authenticate("local"), (req, res) => {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", LOCAL_ORIGIN);
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  console.log("userss: ", req.user);
  let user = UC.filterUserResponse(req.user);
  res.json(user);
});
```

Comment: Ive found that most built in "redirects" just lead me to this type of solution, where I just send a json response and load that url when it gets back to front end. Its crazy how often I need this solution.